# How to fix command not found in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I have a Linux shell script with the below code

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $BASH
name = Mark
echo $name
```

When I run the script, I'm getting an error:

> ./my_script.sh: line 3: =: command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm using [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux).

Comment: Place tall-pointy hat on head and turn and face the corner for 10 minutes....There is no ***space*** allowed surrounding the `=` sign in shell scripting `:)`

Comment: @BenjaminW.- much better dupe. Wonder why that didn't come up in my search? Probably the same reason our "Related" pages are silent.... Good job.

Answer (score 3):

In shell, you need to write:

```
echo $BASH
name=Mark
echo $name
```

Note there are *no* spaces around `=` when setting a variable. The shell usually interprets `name = Mark` as calling the command `name` with arguments `=`and `Mark`, hardly what you intend. It also seems that `name` somehow expands to nothing (an alias?), thus the confusing message about command `=`.